# Importing a .txt file with column header spacings in R

Tags: r

```
company name    person  Salary Of Person
ITC     Jacob   10000
TCS     Ash 20000
Google      Jim 40000
GS      Mark    50000
```

Due to the spacings like "company name", R recognizes "company" as separate column and "name" as separate column. What should I code so that this problem doesn't occur. 
PS : This is just a small part of my file.

Comment: But aren't `company` and `name` in fact two separate columns?  The answer to your question, if there really is a question, is probably to fix your source CSV data.

Comment: No, @TimBiegeleisen . "Person" is the column in which names of person is given i.e Jacob,Ash. How to fix source  csv data? I am completely new to R. The data that I have is approx 40 mb per file

Comment: You need to get quotes around `company name` ... this is the only way which `read.csv` can know to treat it as one column.

Comment: Is the issue in reading in data? In which case you might be reading in as space delimeters and you'll need to use commas or something else. If this issue is inside R, then use backquotes ` ` to refer to the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to your problem would be to fix your source data such that the column names are quoted.  Then you could read using something like the following:

```
read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = "", quote = "\"")
```

For a quick workaround, you can try reading the CSV file without a header:

```
df <- read.csv(file, header = FALSE, sep = "", quote = "\"")
```

Then you can manually assign the column names via:

```
names(df) <- c("company name", "person", "Salary Of Person")
```

This workaround assumes that the remainder of your data is well-behaved, i.e. you don't have more than one entry per column anywhere else.  If you do, then your only option would be to quote/escape everything.